# Trying to connect a remote MySQL Database to Visual Studio 2010 Pro (C++)

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio-2010

Ok guys, I've been trying to get this working for a few weeks in my spare time, and all day today, and I have nothing to show for it, so here's my question.

First off, the end goal for this is to read and write basic information (id #s, names, etc.) from a remote mysql database, to a C++ program written in Visual Studio 2010 Pro, or something equivalent (and free). I access the server from my laptop with SSH, and I can call family members to mess with router settings and such.

I'm trying to use a MySQL database on a Ubuntu Server machine that I access remotely from a Windows 7 laptop. I have installed MySQL Connector C++ from the MySQL website (the msi installer). NOTE: I have not done anything with the Connector install except run the exe I downloaded. Didn't think I needed to compile anything, but I'm wrong a lot. I have created a database, a user who has privileges to the database, and this user can (in theory) connect from any ip, because it is declared as 'username@'%'. I also changed the my.cnf file so that the bind-address line is commented out. I used 'mysqladmin ping -h serveraddress -u username -p' and that gave me 'mysqld is alive', so I'm assuming the database is accessible from any ip remotely. So, I opened up VS 2010 Pro, made a new project, went to tools, and then 'Connect To Database'. I selected Microsoft MySQL Server and put in the information exactly as I did for mysqladmin. I clicked Test Connection and I get an error box that ends with 'provider: Named Pipes Provider, error 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server'. Sorry for the block of text, just want to give all the details I can.

Hopefully I'm close to making this work, I'm not pressed for time but I'm really tired of not being able to work on anything else in the project, since it all branches from this database connection.

Thanks you all! I'll reply with whatever you need me to during the day, I'm not much of a night owl anymore =)

UPDATE:
I have the sample code from the mysql site compiling correctly, it was just a matter of finally getting a few hours to sit down and fix linker/library errors one at a time, downloaded the boost libraries, and changed include directories to direct paths when I could get them to work correctly. Now all I need to do is learn how to use it lol

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the problem but be sure to use the 32 bit ODBC Administrator if you are building a 32 bit application. If you are on a 64 bit PC, by default you are going to be using the 64 bit ODBC Administrator and consequently your 32 bit application won't actually see the DSN that you've created. Run the 32 bit ODBC Administrator using this path:  C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe and then create your DSN.